# angular2 populate ngFor in different grid cells

Tags: angular

I have an array: `hobbies=['Reading','Sport','Travelling','Movies','Cooking','Singing'];`

and in template right now I am populating it manually:

```
<div class="my-checkbox">
    <!-- Hobbies -->
    <span style="float: left; width: 100px;"><h5>Hobbies</h5></span>

    <div class="mdl-grid">
        <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col">
            <label #checkbox_1 class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox" for="checkbox-1">
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1" name="hobbies" value="sport" 
                class="mdl-checkbox__input" >
                <span class="mdl-checkbox__label">Sports</span>
            </label>
            <label #checkbox_2 class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox" for="checkbox-2">
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-2" name="hobbies" value="reading" class="mdl-checkbox__input">
                <span class="mdl-checkbox__label">Reading</span>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col">

            <label #checkbox_3 class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox" for="checkbox-3">
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-3" name="hobbies" value="singing"  
                class="mdl-checkbox__input">
                <span class="mdl-checkbox__label">Singing</span>
            </label>
            <label #checkbox_4 class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox" for="checkbox-4">
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-4" name="hobbies" value="travelling" 
                class="mdl-checkbox__input">
                <span class="mdl-checkbox__label">Travelling</span>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col">
            <label #checkbox_5 class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox" for="checkbox-5">
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-5" name="hobbies" value="movies"  
                class="mdl-checkbox__input">
                <span class="mdl-checkbox__label">Movies</span>
            </label>
            <label #checkbox_6 class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox" for="checkbox-6">
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-6" name="hobbies" value="cooking" 
                class="mdl-checkbox__input">
                <span class="mdl-checkbox__label">Cooking</span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Which looks like following:

[image]

I would like to instead use ngFor to populate these checkboxes but keeping the structure intact i.e. alternate values are inserted into consecutive cells something like:

```
<div class="mdl-grid" *ngFor="let hobby of hobbies">
 <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col">
    <label #checkbox_1 class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox" for="checkbox-1">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1" name="hobbies" value="sport" 
        class="mdl-checkbox__input" >
        <span class="mdl-checkbox__label">{{hobby}}</span>
    </label> 
    <label #checkbox_2 class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox" for="checkbox-1">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1" name="hobbies" value="sport" 
        class="mdl-checkbox__input" >
        <span class="mdl-checkbox__label">{{hobby}}</span>
    </label>                            
 </div>
</div>
```

Also, as this is mdl-stepper `#checkbox_1`or the label is also important because I upgrade elements in my component like following:

```
@ViewChild('checkbox_2') checkbox_2:ElementRef;
@ViewChild('checkbox_3') checkbox_3:ElementRef;
@ViewChild('checkbox_4') checkbox_4:ElementRef;
@ViewChild('checkbox_5') checkbox_5:ElementRef;
@ViewChild('checkbox_6') checkbox_6:ElementRef;

componentHandler.upgradeElement(this.checkbox_1.nativeElement);
componentHandler.upgradeElement(this.checkbox_2.nativeElement);
componentHandler.upgradeElement(this.checkbox_3.nativeElement);
componentHandler.upgradeElement(this.checkbox_4.nativeElement);
componentHandler.upgradeElement(this.checkbox_5.nativeElement);
componentHandler.upgradeElement(this.checkbox_6.nativeElement);
```

How can I achieve this?

**UPDATE:**

When I tried with above mentioned ngFor loop I get like following:

[image]

Comment: look at the pattern with the various components and see how you can extract it into a loop.  what did you try that didn't work?

Comment: I basically tried the same code above in question with ngFor but it populates same value instead of consecutive values, Also, While dynamically populating I am no more sure how can give something like #checkbox_1 so that that element can be upgraded for proper rendering

Comment: are you available in teamviewer?

Comment: unfortunately not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create pipe that will split your array into chunks of 2 elements. It might look like this:

**chunks.pipe.ts**

```
@Pipe({ name: 'chunks' })
export class ChunksPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(arr: any, chunkSize: number) {
    return arr.reduce((prev, cur, index) => (index % chunkSize) ? prev : prev.concat([arr.slice(index, index + chunkSize)]), []);
  }
}
```

And then you can use this `ChunksPipe` like this:

**component.html**

```
<div class="mdl-grid">
  <div *ngFor="let chunk of hobbies | chunks: 2" class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col">
    <label *ngFor="let hobby of chunk" #checkbox class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies" [value]="hobby" class="mdl-checkbox__input">
      <span class="mdl-checkbox__label">{{hobby}}</span>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

To upgrade elements i would get elements via `@ViewChildren`

**component.ts**

```
hobbies = ['Sport', 'Reading', 'Singing', 'Travelling', 'Movies', 'Cooking' ];

@ViewChildren('checkbox') checkboxes: QueryList<ElementRef>;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.checkboxes.forEach(cbx => componentHandler.upgradeElement(cbx.nativeElement));
}
```

P.S. Alternative way is using directive that will do it internally

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/Q3PnWgRKvizACatnIliA?p=preview)**

See also **[Grid Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/q9olLVsEcGrskv8oQkV7?p=preview)**